# Terraform Nested For Loop on an Azure NSG Resource

Tags: azure, for-loop, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have been trying to work out how to get this resource:

```html
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
}
```

To step through my two maps one on NSGS and the other the subnets.

Here is the Subnet Resource Code:

```html
resource "azurerm_subnet" "one_subnet" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.one_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.one_vnet.name
  name                 = each.value["name"]
  address_prefixes     = each.value["address_prefixes"]
}
```

Subnet Variable File:

```html
variable "subnets" {
  type = map(any)
}
```

Subnet TFVar

```html
subnets = {
  subnet_1 = {
    name             = "virtual-subnet"
    address_prefixes = ["10.13.1.0/24"]
  }
  subnet_2 = {
    name             = "virtual-subnet"
    address_prefixes = ["10.13.2.0/24"]
  }
  subnet_3 = {
    name             = "virtual-subnet"
    address_prefixes = ["10.13.3.0/24"]
  }
}
```

NSG Code:

```html
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "one_nsgs" {
  for_each            = var.one_nsgs
  name                = each.value["name"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.one_rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.one_rg.name

  security_rule {}
}
```

NSG Variable File

```html
variable "one_nsgs" {
  type = map(any)
}
```

NSG Tfvars

```html
one_nsgs = {
  devwebnsg = {
    name = "DevWebNSG"
  }
  devapinsg = {
    name = "DevApiNSG"
  }
  devjobsnsg = {
    name = "DevNSG"
  }
}
```

I have tried combining two of the variable maps into a nested map in my locals file and then passing that to the binding NSG resource. But what happens is the Binding NSG Resource wants the id of the resources not the names, which only happens through passing the resource block into the NSG bind resource.

I have also tried this on the NSG Binding Resource:

```html
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "bind_nsg_to_subnet" {
  for_each      = { for entry in local.combined_nsg_and_subnet: "${entry.subnet}.${entry.nsg}" => entry }
  subnet_id                 = each.value.subnet.id
  network_security_group_id = each.value.nsg.id
}
```

This looks at my Locals file map

```html
 # Nested loop over both lists, and flatten the result.
  combined_nsg_and_subnet = distinct(flatten([
    for subnet in var.subnets["name"] : [
      for nsg in var.one_nsgs["name"] : {
        subnet = subnet
        nsg    = nsg
      }
    ]
  ]))
```

But the Id of the resource is not passed in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to combine both `azurerm_subnet` and `azurerm_network_security_group` in a local map and use it for ID, you have to do using resource attributes which will have ID, instead of variables.

For example:

```
combined_nsg_and_subnet = flatten([
  for subnet in azurerm_subnet.one_subnet : [
    for nsg in azurerm_network_security_group.one_nsgs : {
      subnet_id = subnet.id
      nsg_id    = nsg.id
    }
  ]
])
```

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "bind_nsg_to_subnet" {
  for_each = { for entry in local.combined_nsg_and_subnet: "${entry.subnet_id}.${entry.nsg_id}" => entry }
  
  subnet_id                 = each.value.subnet_id
  network_security_group_id = each.value.nsg_id
}
```

Comment: So I now have this issue: │ The "for_each" map includes keys derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full set of keys that will identify the   
│ instances of this resource.
│
│ When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to define the map keys statically in your configuration and place apply-time results only in the map values.
│
│ Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a second time to fully converge.

Comment: Have you come accross that before?

Comment: It's not an issue @Jason, that's just how Terraform works in these situations, you'll have to break your workflow into 2 Terraform apply commands, one using the `-target` flag specifying the creation of the subnets and security groups resources, and another one for the association (you can omit the `-target` flag here).